# Is it necessary to use # for creating temp tables in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is it necessary to use `#` before creating a temporary table in SQL server?

Example:

```
SELECT column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar 
INTO ItemBack1 
FROM table2
WHERE table2.ID = 7
```

For ItemBack1 is it necessary to use the `#` symbol?

If not, then what is the use of `#` in creating temp tables?

Comment: Yes. # creates temporary table. Without it creates a table.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Yes. You need to prefix the table name with "#" (hash) to create temporary tables.

If you do NOT need the table later, go ahead & create it.
     Temporary Tables are very much like normal tables. However, it gets created in tempdb.
Also, it is only accessible via the current session i.e. For EG: if another user tries to access the temp table created by you, he'll not be able to do so.

"##" (double-hash creates "Global" temp table that can be accessed by other sessions as well.

Refer the below link for the Basics of Temporary Tables:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server-2005

If the content of your table is less than 5000 rows & does NOT contain data types such as nvarchar(MAX), varbinary(MAX), consider using Table Variables.

<s>They are the fastest as they are just like any other variables which are stored in the RAM.</s> [They are stored in tempdb as well, not in RAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386).

```
DECLARE @ItemBack1 TABLE
(
 column1 int,
 column2 int,
 someInt int,
 someVarChar nvarchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @ItemBack1
SELECT column1, 
       column2, 
       someInt, 
       someVarChar 
  FROM table2
 WHERE table2.ID = 7;
```

More Info on Table Variables:
http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx

Comment: In SQL Server, the SELECT syntax is INSERT INTO @ItemBack1 SELECT column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar FROM table2 WHERE table2.ID = 7

Comment: Variable tables are not stored in RAM, they are also stored in tempdb. I would recommend to not use table variables unless you understand some of their downsides, as their rowcounts are automatically set to one, and bad plans can result.

Comment: Can you give a source for the 5000 rows, nvarchar(max), varbinary(max) restrictions? This is allowed, but I'm not sure why it is not recommended.

Comment: I too thought table variables were stored in memory.  I stand corrected: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/23720

Comment: I'm only going to comment too that it is a fact that table variables are stored in tempdb.  I'm commenting so maybe MORE people read comments and get it in there heads as I am so tired of walking into a joint as a senior consultant to have to argue with a full-time employee that is ignorant and tries to say otherwise.  I'm talking over dozens of companies in Fortune 500 ,  so  glad to see people comment.   SADLY, unless this OP that answers the question actually EDITS their answer , we will continue to have this ignorant persisting for another decade or so.

Comment: I considered using a table variable, but needed a GO after using it in an UPDATE and before using it in an INSERT. I don't suppose there is a good way around that (other than a temp or permanent table)?

Answer (score 14):

The difference between this two tables `ItemBack1` and `#ItemBack1` is that the first on is persistent (permanent) where as the other is temporary.

Now if take a look at your question again

> Is it necessary to Use # for creating temp table in sql server?

The answer is **Yes**, because without this preceding `#` the table will not be a temporary table, it will be independent of all sessions and scopes.