# Is it necessary to Use @ for creating table variables in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Declare @Mytable TABLE
(

 Field2 INT,
 Field2 VARCHAR(MAX)

)
```

Is this "@" is necessary When creating an **Table Variable** in Sql Server

thanks in advnc.

Comment: interesting that you asked the same question for temporary tables. what is your motivation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749045/is-it-necessary-to-use-for-creating-temp-table-in-sql-server

Comment: i have doubt on this , i am new to table variables

Comment: -1 No research effort shown. Looking in the docs would have told you [@table_variable_name Is the name of a variable of type table. Variable names must begin with an at (@) sign and conform to the rules for identifiers.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, variable names in TSQL must have @ character as their first character

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to specify @ to declare any variable type. In case if you don't want that then you can either use temporary tables as

CREATE TABLE #
(

```
<col_name> <datatype>
```

)