# optimizing a table's performance using temporary table in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Good day, I'm quite a newbie in optimizing database queries...actually it's my very first time... I've done my research and found out that using temporary tables could help me improve the queries performance..  Aside from other solutions like using index but though their are a lot of blogs about it I haven't yet to find a well detailed tutorial about it... I was hoping if you could kindly help. Given this sample table...

Table Schemas::

```
    StudentInfo:
    StudentID 
    LAstname
    FirstName
    YearCode
    SectionCode

    TeacherInfo:
    SectionCode
    TeacherID
    TeacherName


    GradeInfo:
    StudentID
    AverageGrade

    CashierRecord:
    StudentID
    EnrolledDate
    ModeOfPayment
    AmountDue
```

Query I have Tried...

```
 Select 
        s.StudentID,
        s.FirstName,
        s.LastName,
        t.Teacher,
        g.AverageGrade,
        c.EnrolledDate
    From StudentInfo s
    LEFT JOIN TeacherInfo t ON s.StudentID= t.StudentID
    LEFT JOIN GradeInfo g ON s.StudentID= g.StudentID
    LEFT JOIN GradeRecords c ON s.StudentID= c.StudentID
```

If the given query would retrieve a huge amount of data (ex. 100,000 records) the query would surely run low in performance...   may you kindly explain how could I utilize TEMPORARY TABLES to store the data from multiple tables so that retrieval could be easier...

Comment: Did you check that you have indexes on all compared columns (StudentID)? Could you provide some exampledata?

Comment: What do you mean with retrieval? Do you want to process all returned data or a filtered set?

Comment: yah I almost forgot since I just made up an example problem... they all actually have PK which counts as clustered index.. but index aside... what I've read is 1)create a temporary table 2)populate it with the data from your old table(having datas from different tables)  3. select the data from the temp table 4. drop table... how does that actually improve the performance of a select query in fetching large amounts of data?

Comment: Left joins perform slower than inner joins.  If you can, change them to inner joins.  For example, do you really want to return students without any teachers?  A left join would still return the data where an inner join would skip that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a table from a select result in SQL server you could use `select into`.

```
Select 
    s.StudentID,
    s.FirstName,
    s.LastName,
    t.Teacher,
    g.AverageGrade,
    c.EnrolledDate
into TEMPTABLE
From StudentInfo s
LEFT JOIN TeacherInfo t ON s.StudentID= t.StudentID
LEFT JOIN GradeInfo g ON s.StudentID= g.StudentID
LEFT JOIN GradeRecords c ON s.StudentID= c.StudentID
```

Then you could use `TEMPTABLE` and then drop it using

```
drop table TEMPTABLE
```

With this you have collected your data to one table. TEMPTABLE is not yet a real temporary table. Look here to find more on that ([Is it necessary to use # for creating temp tables in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749045/is-it-necessary-to-use-for-creating-temp-table-in-sql-server)). It comes down to write `#TEMPTABLE`.

But to build this table you still have the processing time of your select.

Comment: Thank you very much I've been doing that but I have another question in mind.. I actually have a lot of JOINS about 20 of them making it really long to process my query though I've use a temporary table to retrieve them.. could you give me advice on how could I further enhance my query performance...

Comment: Again my suggestion to check indexes. If I unterstood right, you have PKs but is an index e.g. on TeacherInfo.StudentID? Here (s.StudentID= t.StudentID) the PK of TeacherInfo is not used if the queryplan does evaluate your tables in order of occurance.