# SQL Server: what do tables named #ABCDEF01 contain?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I execute request

```
select * 
from tempdb.sys.objects
where type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
```

and see tables named like `#AB12CD34`, `#ABCDEF01`, etc.

I don't use such naming convention for temp tables. Is that possible to determine real names for these tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to use # for creating temp tables in SQL server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749045/is-it-necessary-to-use-for-creating-temp-tables-in-sql-server)

Comment: I have not found these mention table my temp db. I agree that these are temp table and dropped automatically when session/connection is closed.

Comment: @Igor Not really a duplication. Question you suggested as original is about how to name temp tables. My one is about how to restore a name of existed table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the system naming convention for standard temporary tables.

Temporary tables will generally show up as a 128 character name in the format

```
#YourTempTableName______________ ... _________00000000000D
```

Where the hex at the end acts to prevent collisions between different sessions.

Tables named `#AB12CD34` are either table variables/table valued parameters or they are cached temporary tables from stored procedures.

When the stored procedure finishes executing a temp table can be cached so it does not have to be re-created again on next use. The `FCheckAndCleanupCachedTempTable` transaction renames the temp tables to this format [as part of this process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13412/3690).

[More about temporary table caching in this blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422150925/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/17/temporary-object-caching-explained.aspx).

The cached temp tables belong to the execution context of a cached execution plan. You can see stored procedures with cached execution contexts with

```
SELECT DB_NAME(dbid)               AS DatabaseName,
       OBJECT_NAME(objectid, dbid) AS ObjectName
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
       CROSS apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) t
       JOIN sys.dm_os_memory_objects m1
         ON m1.memory_object_address = cp.memory_object_address
       JOIN sys.dm_os_memory_objects m2
         ON m1.page_allocator_address = m2.page_allocator_address
WHERE  m2.type = 'MEMOBJ_EXECUTE'
       AND cp.objtype = 'Proc'
```

You can also see cached temp tables with

```
select *
from sys.dm_os_memory_cache_entries
where name='tempdb' AND entry_data LIKE '<entry database_id=''2'' entity_type=''object'' entity_id=''-%'
```

But I don't see any way of linking these together to see which plan caches what temp object.

You could look at the column names and see if you recognize the table structure from one of your procs.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   tempdb.sys.objects
         WHERE  type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
                AND name = '#' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(object_id AS BINARY(4)), 2))
SELECT T.name,
       c.name,
       type_name(c.user_type_id) AS Type
FROM   T
       JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c
         ON c.object_id = T.object_id;
```

Comment: Martin, last script is definitely the one I need, thx a lot. The single unclear item left: do these cached object keep table structure only, or structure and data? Is that possible to loose a lot of disk space on these caches, or get some security problems?

Comment: They just keep the metadata about table structure and a single 8K IAM page and 8K data page to avoid contention from potentially having to allocate and deallocate these again. So unlikely to add up to anything significant in terms of tempdb space. There is no particular security issue. One session can't see another previous session's contents.

Answer (score 3):

Any table that starts with '#' is a temporary table that exists until the session or connection is lost. The table is visible only within the current session. Any table that starts with '##' is a similar type table except that it is global in nature and other sessions / connections can see it.

Comment: Randy, some of these tables are created 3 days ago. Is that possible to define which session\connection created it? Principal_id is null.

Comment: The naming convention shown in the question is not the one used in the system tables for standard temporary tables. This is either a table variable or a cached temporary table from a stored procedure.