# Temporary table subsitute in sql server

Tags: sql-server

So guys this is my code with a temporary table

```
            SELECT
                cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_id AS
                datatobeupdated,ERSBusinessLogic_ID
                INTO temptable1
            FROM cosd.erscommoditydataseries INNER JOIN cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes
                ON 
                SUBSTRING(
                cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_sourceseriesid,
                CHARINDEX('(', cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_sourceseriesid)
                + 1,
                CHARINDEX(')',
                cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_sourceseriesid)
                -
                CHARINDEX('(',
                cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_sourceseriesid) - 1) =
                SUBSTRING(
                cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination,
                CHARINDEX('(', cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination)
                + 1, CHARINDEX(')',
                cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination) -
                CHARINDEX('(',
                cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination)
                - 1)
                INNER JOIN cosd.ERSBusinessLogic   

                ON
                cosd.ERSBusinessLogic.ERSBusinessLogic_ID=ERSConstructedVariable_BusinessLogicID
            where erscommodity_sourceseriesid LIKE '%(N%'
            AND cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination
            LIKE '%CV(N%'
            AND cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_newdataseriesid
            IS
            NULL


            update cosd.ERSConstructedVariablesOutcomes set ERSConstructedVariable_NewDataSeriesID=_dummy.datatobeupdated
            from cosd.ERSConstructedVariablesOutcomes dummy  JOIN temptable1 _dummy
            on dummy.ERSConstructedVariable_BusinessLogicID= _dummy.ERSBusinessLogic_ID
```

but I try to execute twice,it ofcourse says temptable1 already exists, but is there any other way to execute this code. I want the output of the select query to be updated into the table given in the update table

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749045/is-it-necessary-to-use-for-creating-temp-tables-in-sql-server

Comment: INTO temptable1 is not a temp table at all.. it's a permanent table called temptable1. what you want is #temptable1. Before you use it in the code.. just check to ensure that it doesn't exist and drop it if it does (helps if your query crashes and burns mid way and you need to restart) always drop your #temp tables when you are done with them.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a temp (or local) table:

```
        ;WITH _dummy as (
        SELECT
            cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_id AS
            datatobeupdated,ERSBusinessLogic_ID
        FROM cosd.erscommoditydataseries INNER JOIN cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes
            ON 
            SUBSTRING(
            cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_sourceseriesid,
            CHARINDEX('(', cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_sourceseriesid)
            + 1,
            CHARINDEX(')',
            cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_sourceseriesid)
            -
            CHARINDEX('(',
            cosd.erscommoditydataseries.erscommodity_sourceseriesid) - 1) =
            SUBSTRING(
            cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination,
            CHARINDEX('(', cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination)
            + 1, CHARINDEX(')',
            cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination) -
            CHARINDEX('(',
            cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination)
            - 1)
            INNER JOIN cosd.ERSBusinessLogic   

            ON
            cosd.ERSBusinessLogic.ERSBusinessLogic_ID=ERSConstructedVariable_BusinessLogicID
        where erscommodity_sourceseriesid LIKE '%(N%'
        AND cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_outputdestination
        LIKE '%CV(N%'
        AND cosd.ersconstructedvariablesoutcomes.ersconstructedvariable_newdataseriesid
        IS
        NULL
        )
        update cosd.ERSConstructedVariablesOutcomes set ERSConstructedVariable_NewDataSeriesID=_dummy.datatobeupdated
        from cosd.ERSConstructedVariablesOutcomes dummy  
        JOIN _dummy
        on dummy.ERSConstructedVariable_BusinessLogicID= _dummy.ERSBusinessLogic_ID
```